# Two Oracle databases on a Windows 2003 server...how to determine which database sqplus / as sysdba connects to?

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I've tried setting my login's (which was the login used to install the software long ago) oracle_sid environment to database1, but sqlplus / as sysdba insists on connected to database2.  What am I missing?

Comment: Sqlplus depends on $ORACLE_HOME + $ORACLE_SID, which are currently set in the context. Before running it do `echo $ORACLE_HOME` and then `echo $ORACLE_SID` and see that it will point to database2. This is something which is most probably set in the bash_profile for the user you're running sqlplus with. Do examine that, do : `cat /home/user/.bash_profile`. Btw, it's a good idea to paste the results here, for reference. Thanks

Comment: It's a windows machine.  Those are unix/linux commands, no?

Comment: `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` ; `echo %ORACLE_SID%` then ... in this case I guess that those are the ones you need to change, in order to "switch" between databases. Also, check what your PATH env variable has in it, related t Oracle products and put them here, in the body of the question above.